# Set Outlook 2013 font color in the registry

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-office-2013

I want to set the default font color in Outlook 2013 via registry but I can't find the right key. 
Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: why do you want to do it in registry instead of setting directly in OutLook?

Comment: @Máté Juhász
That's because in the end I want to do it with GPOs. And you can't set the font color directly via GPOs.

Comment: it's borderline to be off-topic being corporate environment. You may find more experience at [serverfault stackexchange](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Máté Juhász Thanks for the advice. I'll ask it there. I didn't know that that forum exists.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/246703)...